# C++Math evaluating incorrectly

Tags: c++

I thought I can make life a little easier in data statistics by making a small program which returns the results of sampling distribution of the mean (with standard error). It does this part successfully but in an attempt to return the z-score by using the formula I found [here](http://www.onlinemathlearning.com/image-files/normal-distribution_4.gif), it returns `-1#IND`. My interpretation of that formula is:

```
((1 / (sqrt(2 * pi) * stdev)) * pow(e, (normalpow))
```

where

```
double normalpow = -0.5 * ((mean - popmean) * (mean-popmean) / stdev)
```

I did a little more investigating and found that `(mean - popmean) * (mean - popmean)` was evaluating to `0` no matter what. How can I get around this problem of `normalpow` evaluating to `0`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

double number  ;
double mean ;
double popmean ;
double stdev ;
double square = 2;
double e = 2.71828182845904523536;
double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
double normalpow = -0.5*((mean-popmean)*(mean-popmean)/stdev);
int main ()
{
    string continuer ;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter Sample Mean: " << endl;
        cin >> mean;
        cout << "Enter Population Mean: " << endl;
        cin >> popmean;
        cout << "Enter Standard Deviation: " << endl;
        cin >> stdev;
        cout << "Enter Sample Size: " << endl;
        cin >> number;
        if (stdev == 0)
            cout << ((mean-popmean)/(number))<< endl;
        else
        {
            cout << ((mean-popmean)/((stdev)/(sqrt(number))))<< endl;
            cout << ((1/(sqrt(2*pi)*stdev))*pow(e, (normalpow)))<< endl;
        }
        cout << "If you want to continue, Press Y" << endl ;
        cin >> continuer;
    } while (continuer == "Y" || continuer == "y") ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so what are `mean` and `popmean`?

Comment: What variable types are mean and popmean?  May need to cast them as floats or doubles to avoid integer truncation.

Comment: I set mean and popmean as a double for now. My test subject was 9 for mean and 10 for popmean.

Comment: If you are using `int`s to perform some operations like division, you should know that the result will be truncated, so, for example after `int a = 1/2`, `a` will store 0. The same will happen in this case: `double b = 1/2`, because you are performing a division between integers and casting the result to a double (implicitly). One way to solve this issue is using, for example `double b = 1.0/2.0`, which will make a division between `double`

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and verified the values are what you expect?  You could also try -0.5f instead of -0.5 just to be explicit.

Comment: Can you provide a few lines of code that reproduce the problem?

Comment: Alright one sec I'll go through your suggestions to see if they work. @juanchopanza I'll edit my question to include all the code.

Comment: Ok I posted the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using namespace std;

double number  ;
double mean ;
double popmean ;
double stdev ;
double square = 2;
double e = 2.71828182845904523536;
double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
double normalpow = -0.5*((mean-popmean)*(mean-popmean)/stdev);
```

These are all variables with static storage duration, so those without explicit initialisers are initialised to 0.

Hence `mean`, `popmean` and `stdev` are all 0 when `normalpow` is initialised, and that initialisation results in

```
double normalpow = -0.5*(0.0*0.0/0.0);
```

which gives a NaN.

You never change `normalpow` afterwards, so any computation involving it results in a NaN.

Comment: Fair enough. Should I declare the function later in the body of the code because all the values gets defined there?

Comment: Yes, or you should take juanchopanza's advice and define a real function to get `normalpow`.

Comment: That works actually. I am an idiot for not noticing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
double normalpow = -0.5*((mean-popmean)*(mean-popmean)/stdev);
```

At this point, `mean`, `popmean` and `stdev` have garbage values because they haven't been initialized. It sounds like what you want is a function.

```
double normalPow(double mean, double popmean, double stddev)
{
  return -0.5*((mean-popmean)*(mean-popmean)/stdev);
}
```

Then call it in your main:

```
double normalpow = normalPow(mean, popmean, stdev);
```

Of course, you should check for `stdev` equal or close to `0.` in the function.

Comment: Ooo nice bit of advice there as well.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how `mean` and `popmean` are calculated. `mean - popmean` evaluates to zero, if they are identical: `mean == popmean`.

Comment: The thing is I swapped them around so that it was (popmean-mean)*(popmean-mean) and it has the same results.

Comment: Of course, if mean == popmean, then mean - popmean == popmean - mean. That's not surprising. How and where do you calculate both numbers?

Answer (score 0):

And the formula you are using is not correct cause you are not calculating the square of  the standard deviation.

Comment: I thought the two (mean-popmean)*(mean-popmean) was squared.

Comment: Yes it is but you should also do " pow(stdv,2)".